# APC SMX1500RMI2UNC connect battery

Tags: ups

I have a brand new APC SMX1500RMI2UNC which I installed last night.

All was good and running well last night.  When I woke up this morning it is beeping with an error saying connect battery.

So I reseated all the battery connections in it and the additional battery set.  The alarm was still beeping.

Unplugged the power cord to the unit and the system immediately switched to batteries.  Plugged the power in and system returned to normal.

Left it for a few minutes and it started beeping again with the same condition.

The instructions do not indicate anything additional required to get the unit operational.

Can anyone suggest why this would be happening on a brand new unit?

Comment: Take it the batt's where also new with the unit? I've see this before and it was down to bad batt's - the logs where full of 'batt disconnected' and 'reconnected' alarms even though nothing had been touched.

Comment: Yes, APC have replaced the unit today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defective UPS unit replaced by manufacturer.